# Title in R corrplot too not centred and too high

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I am using corrplot to visualise correlations, however the title is quite high above the plot, and I would like to bring it closer.  How do I do this?

Sample dataframe:

```
"VADeaths" <-
  structure(c(11.7, 18.1, 26.9, 41, 66, 8.7, 11.7, 20.3, 30.9, 54.3, 15.4, 
  24.3, 37, 54.6, 71.1, 8.4, 13.6, 19.3, 35.1, 50), .Dim = c(5, 4),
  .Dimnames = list(c("50-54", "55-59", "60-64", "65-69", "70-74"),
  c("Rural Male", "Rural Female", "Urban Male", "Urban Female")))
```

Calculate the correlation and visualise

```
library(corrplot)
cors = cor(VADeaths)

corrplot(cors,tl.col="black",title="Example Plot",mar=c(0,0,5,0),tl.offset = 1)
```

By extending the margin to 5 above the plot I can at least get the title to appear in the plot, but cannot figure out how to bring the title closer to the plot and centred over the plot rather than also the space taken up by the labels.

The above looks like this:

[image]

I am wanting something more like this (ignore the fonts)

[image]

My actual plots have much smaller labels, so there is a gap of around 3-4cm between the labels and the title.  I did not find that increasing the value in mar solved the issue.

Comment: Based on the way `corrplot` is drawing the figure, you have no easy programmatic way to know where the box boundaries are based on the function input or output. I think your truly best bet would be to take the [source of `corrplor`](https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot/blob/master/R/corrplot.R) and modify it so that you can either (a) know where the box boundary is, or (b) find a way to center the title yourself.

Comment: @dww thanks for fixing the images in my question - how do I control the size of images?  I'd like to avoid someone needing to edit my questions in future.

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `mtext` to add the title instead

```
corrplot(cors,tl.col="black", mar=c(0,0,5,0), tl.offset = 1)
mtext("Example Plot", at=2.5, line=-0.5, cex=2)
```

`at` controls the horizontal position. `line` controls the height. `cex` for the size. `?mtext` to see more options

Comment: Do you need `side = 3`?

Comment: @r2evans, side = 3 is the default

Comment: Huh, good call, sorry. (I've always preferred to be explicit with it, so I never checked.)

Comment: I've tried running this line after my corrplot code but am met with the error: "Error in mtext("Correlation Table of Numeric Variables", at = 2.5, line = -0.5,  : 
  plot.new has not been called yet). Any ideas how I can resolve this? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can draw a correlation plot using ggplot2.

First convert the correaltion data to be a data frame.

```
library(reshape2)
cors <- cor(VADeaths)
cor_data <- reshape2::melt(
  cors, 
  varnames = paste0("demographic", 1:2), 
  value.name = "correlation"
)
```

Then draw the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(cor_data, aes(demographic1, demographic2, fill = correlation)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  ggtitle("Correlation across demographics for VA deaths")
```

[image: a correlation plot of demographics in the VA deaths dataset, created using ggplot2]